# Making an IB contract: Directory for IBpY exchanges and commodity codes?

Tags: programming, futures, python, commodities, interactive-brokers

All the tutorials for making a contract seem to use either Apple or Google as examples:

goog_contract = create_contract('GOOG', 'STK', 'SMART', 'SMART', 'USD')

If I want to trade CME Feeder Cattle futures - how do I confirm I'm using the correct contract ticker (in IB it's GF), Futures and Exchange designation?

Is there a master list of exchanges and tickers someone can kindly point me to :)

http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/livestock/feeder-cattle.html

Answer (score 1):

IB has a search portal where you can look up contracts:

https://pennies.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.9/index.php